# I'm having some trouble with this definite integral

Tags: integration

Im trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\Pi /3}sin(2x)e^{Cos(2x)}dx$$

I have tried using U substitution letting u = 2x, and du = 2dx, giving

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\Pi  /3}sin(u)e^{Cos(u)}du$$

then again letting w = cos(u), and dw = -sin(u)du, giving

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{-1/2}e^{w}dw$$
ive swapped the bounds and inverted the sign of the constant, and when I evaluate it i get:
$$\frac{e}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}$$

Is this the correct answer? Shouldn't I have to substitute u and w back into the equation?

Comment: I don't think you substitute u and w back in as long as you change the limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing limits after every substitution, you don't have substitute anything back.

Your solution and answer are correct

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct. As you substituted the bounds as well there is no need of substituting back.
An alternativ to approach this task would be to ignore the bounds as long as you substitute, substitute back and afterwards use the old bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. You have changed the limits after every step where you substituted, you do not have to substitute them back.